# How to append sibling element to previous element using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the time and meridian which are seperated by span tags. Both the time and meridian are in span tags and are siblings. I want to append the tags aswell so(11:40, am -> 11:40 am) and have no idea. Here is my code.

```
***
browser.implicitly_wait(20)

#depart = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'top'})
date = soup.find_all('div', {'class': ['depart-time', 'base-time']})
#meri = soup.select('span.depart-time.base-time').find_next_sibling('span')

for dates in date.find_all('div', {'class': ['depart-time', 'base-time']}):
print(dates.text)
***
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert_after()`:

```
<old_div></old_div><new_div></new_div>
```

Or `insert_before()`:

```
<new_div></new_div><old_div></old_div>
```

More examples are given in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert).